# Identifying a property of contiuous of functions and its proof

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I am reading a proof of the EVT (http://math.umn.edu/~kling202/hamline/calculus/Chapter4/EVTProof.pdf) and I came across this property of continuous functions (i.e., taking the limit outside of the brackets):

[image]

I have been struggling to idenitfy this particular property and locate its proof, however, the closest I have came to is this:

[image]

Now, I'm not certain whether the above theorem corresponds to the property mentioned in the paper since $d_n$ is being treated as a variable, I believe.

So, I was wondering whether the theorem does correspond to the property and if there exists a proof for the property if the theorem doesn't correspond to the property.

Comment: Note that the first equality is merely substitution (I assume $d$ is defined to be $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}d_n),$ and if you omit the first equality and the term that follows it, then you simply have the (sequence) definition of continuity. I'm not sure what the last term is there for, however.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Sorry, what exactly are you referring to by "the term that follows it"? Are you referring to the second equality? (The last term isnt relevant to the question really, it's relevant only in context)

Comment: By "the term that follows it", I mean $f(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} d_n).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof given is a little bit obscure, almost flawed.

Assume that $f$ doesn't have a finite maximum.

Then there's a sequence $(c_n)$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f(c_n) > n$ for all $n$. $(d_n)$ is a subsequence constructed from $(c_n)$ that converges to a point in $[a,b]$. The construction should also guarantee that $f(d_n) > n$, which is not hard to do:

Let $a_1 = a, b_1 = b$, and $d_1 = c_1$.

Given $I_n = [a_n, b_n]$, infinitely many $c_k$ are in the left or in the right half of $I_n$. If the left half has infinitely many $c_k$, let $I_{n+1}$ be that half, otherwise let $I_{n+1}$ be the right half.

There are $c_k\in I_{n+1}$ with $k \ge n+1$; let $c_{n+1} = c_k$ for the least such $k$, so that $f(d_{n+1}) = f(c_k) > k \ge n+1$.

*Note:* The existence of both sequences $(c_n)$ and $(d_n)$ follows from the Axiom of Dependent Choice.

By construction, $d = \lim_n d_n$ converges to the unique point in $\bigcap_n I_n$, and $d\in [a,b]$. By continuity, $\lim_n f(d_n)$ must exist too, and
$$
\lim_n f(d_n) = f(\lim_n d_n) = f(d). 
$$
But also by construction, the limit on the left does *not* exist: $\lim_n f(d_n) = +\infty$.

So the assumption that $f$ doesn't have a finite maximum must be false.

Comment: Yeah, I recokned too that some parts of the proof were a bit non-rigorous and "obscure", to say the least, too. However, I was wondering whether your exact argument would work for proving the existence of a minimum for $f(x)$ by applying the same argument on $-f(x)$?

Comment: Well *that* is a lot less work ;/ Given that continuous functions achieve their supremum (have a maximum), if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then so is $-f$, thus $-f$ on $[a,b]$ is bounded above and there's $c\in [a,b]$ such that $-f(c) = \sup_{x\in [a.b]} f(x)$. It's straightforward to show that for any set $X$, if $X$ is bounded above then $-X$ is bounded below, and $\sup - X = - \inf X$. The result for minima follows.

Comment: But of course you're welcome to rework the construction into its dual, assuming that $f$ is unbounded below, creating a sequence $(c_n)$ such that $f(c_n) < -n$ for all $n$, and so on.

Comment: Oh, sorry that should have been raher evident. Thanks a lot for your help anyway.

Comment: No prob, thank you.